# Copy constructor destructor and assignment operator for class storing pointers to another class

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm new here and this is my first question. I have a question about my homework assignment. I'm asked to design an abstract class "Base" which is inherited by the class "Sub" (in the assignment there are sub1, sub2 etc but I have tried to narrow it down as much as possible). Then, I should design a class "BasePtr" which stores a pointer to a "Base" object. Finally, baseptr:s are to be stored in a std::vector, and written to a file using ostream_iterator and copy. The file should then be read with a ifstream_iterator, and stored in a std::list.

I have solved the above problem, but I have some problems when implementing the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator (since I am dynamically allocating memory in my BasePtr class I believe that those should be present).

This is the main program.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include "baseptr.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{  
    vector<BasePtr> basevec;
    basevec.push_back( BasePtr(new Sub(1, 4)) );
    basevec.push_back( BasePtr(new Sub(3, 5)) );

    ofstream os("fil.dat");
    ostream_iterator<BasePtr> baseout(os,"\n");
    copy( basevec.begin(), basevec.end(), baseout);
    os.close();

    ifstream is("fil.dat");
    istream_iterator<BasePtr> basein(is), endofbasein;
    list<BasePtr> baselist(basein, endofbasein );

    for (list<BasePtr>::iterator it = baselist.begin(); it != baselist.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << endl;    
}
```

The BasePtr class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "base.h"

using namespace std;

class BasePtr {
public: 
    BasePtr() : basevar(0) {}
    BasePtr(Base *bin) {basevar = bin->clone(); delete bin;}
    const BasePtr & operator=( BasePtr & baseptr ); // assignment operator
    BasePtr(const BasePtr &baseptr ); // copy constructor
    ~BasePtr(); // destructor
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream &os, const BasePtr &baseptr); 
    friend istream& operator>>( istream &is, BasePtr &baseptr); 
private:
    Base* basevar;
};

const BasePtr & BasePtr::operator=( BasePtr & baseptr ) {
    if (this != &baseptr) {
        delete basevar;
        basevar = baseptr.basevar->clone();
    }
    return *this;
}

BasePtr::BasePtr( const BasePtr &baseptr ) {
    if (baseptr.basevar != 0)
        basevar = baseptr.basevar->clone();
}

BasePtr::~BasePtr() {
    if ( basevar != 0 )
        delete basevar;
    basevar = 0;
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream &os, const BasePtr &baseptr) {
    os << *baseptr.basevar;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>( istream &is, BasePtr &baseptr) {
    string name;
    if (!(is >> name))
        return is;
    Base *b = 0;
    if ( name == "SUB" ) 
        b = new Sub();  
    is >> *b;
    baseptr.basevar = b->clone();
    delete b;
    return is;
}
```

and the Base and Sub classes

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public: 
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0; 
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream &os, Base &b) {
        b.print(os); 
        return os;}
    friend istream& operator>>( istream &is, Base &b) {b.readStream(is); return is;}
protected:
    Base(const double xin) : x(xin) {}
    double x;
    virtual ostream& print(ostream &os) const = 0; 
    virtual void readStream( istream &is ) = 0;

};


class Sub : public Base{
public:
    Sub() : Base(0), size(0) {}
    Sub(double xin, double si) : Base(xin), size(si) {}
    ~Sub() {};
    Sub* clone() const {return new Sub(*this);}
private:
    double size;
    Sub(const Sub &p) : Base(p.x), size(p.size) {}
protected:
    virtual ostream& print(ostream &os) const {os << "SUB " <<  x << " " << size << endl; 
        return os; }
    virtual void readStream( istream &is ) {
        is >> x;
        is >> size;
    }

};
```

If I comment out the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator the program builds and runs, and outputs the desired result. However, valgrind finds loads of memory leaks (obviously). If I include these functions, the program ends with Segmentation fault: 11. I am using a mac with os x 10.8 and the clang compiler. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are comparing pointer with 0 in `destructor` and `copy-constructor`. Use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: This won't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug in your program is probably in the copy constructor:

```
BasePtr::BasePtr( const BasePtr &baseptr ) {
    if (baseptr.basevar != 0)
        basevar = baseptr.basevar->clone();
    else {
        basevar = 0; // <<<< missing
    }
}
```

Without this change the following code will produce errors:

```
BasePtr a; // a.basevar = 0
BasePtr b = a; // now b.basevar is not initialized
// destruction of b will call delete on an uninitialized pointer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Danvil, that solved it. After ten years of Matlab programming C++ feels complicated...

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal - And memory leaks mysteriously gone either?

Comment: @SChepurin Probably not, but OP's problem was not memory leaks. The problem was segmentation fault.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I still have one memory problem when reading the file into the list<BasePtr> baselist. Since I am using base->clone() to make a copy of the object, I have one "extra" base instance, which I think that I should delete, but I am not sure where. Valgrind says (excerpt)

==3444== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3444==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3444==    by 0x401BA8: Sub::clone() const (base.h:26)
==3444==    by 0x40131C: BasePtr::BasePtr(BasePtr const&) (baseptr.h:30)

Comment: @danieldahlin You make copies many times in your code. You will have to profile it to see where the leak is happenning. Also, since your code can be divided in two parts (write to file and read from file), you can check a section at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't initializing `basevar` in your `BasePtr` copy constructor, change it to the following:

```
BasePtr::BasePtr( const BasePtr &baseptr ) : basevar{} {
    if (baseptr.basevar != 0)
        basevar = baseptr.basevar->clone();
}
```